# AS3 TimerEvents:

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer

having problems adding parts of a snake on through timer events

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Snake extends MovieClip{

        private const SPEED         :uint = 50;//lower = faster
        private const snakeAttach   :uint = 400;//lower = faster
        private const DIM           :int = 71; //keep this number uneven to have the snake starting in the middle
        private const INITIAL_SIZE  :int = 3; //keep this lower then DIM/2

        private var stopped         :Boolean;
        private var left            :Boolean;
        private var right           :Boolean;
        private var up              :Boolean;
        private var down            :Boolean;
        private var size            :Number;
        private var food            :Sprite;
        private var tmr             :Timer;
        private var addSnake        :Timer;
        private var curI            :Number;
        private var curJ            :Number;
        private var snake           :Array;
        private var grid            :Array;

        public function Snake(){
            size = stage.stageWidth / DIM; //change grid size
            curI = curJ = Math.floor(DIM * 0.5); //change grid size

            initSnake();
            fillGrid();


            addSnake = new Timer(snakeAttach);
            addSnake.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,placeFood);
            addSnake.start();

            tmr = new Timer(SPEED);
            tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,move);
            tmr.start();

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,changeDir);
        }

        private function fillGrid():void{  //grid
            grid = Make2DArray();

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < DIM; i++){
                for (var j:uint = 0; j < DIM; j++){
                    var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
                    sp.graphics.beginFill(0xF0F0F0);
                    sp.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xF5F5F5);
                    sp.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size  - 1, size - 1);
                    sp.x = i * size;
                    sp.y = j * size;
                    addChild(sp);
                    grid[i][j] = sp;
                }
            }   
        }

        private function Make2DArray():Array{   //for the grid
            var a:Array = new Array(DIM);
            for(var i:uint = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                a[i] = new Array(DIM);
            }   
            return a;
        }

        private function initSnake():void{ //initialises the snake
            var center:Number = Math.floor(DIM * 0.5) * size;

            snake = new Array(INITIAL_SIZE);

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < INITIAL_SIZE; i++){
                var sp:Sprite = makeItem();      //adds a body part of makeItem 
                sp.x = center;
                sp.y = center + i * size;
                addChild(sp); //adds to the stage
                snake[i] = sp;  //sets the index to one
            }

            snake.reverse();
        }

        private function makeItem(c:uint = 0):Sprite{  //graphics for item
            var s:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
            s.graphics.beginFill(c);
            s.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x333333);
            s.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
            return s;
        }

        private function placeFood(event:TimerEvent):void{   
            var rndI:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * DIM);  //sets a random integer based on the the floor
            var rndJ:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * DIM);

            var rndX:Number = grid[rndI][rndJ].x; // sets a grid position for the food item to go
            var rndY:Number = grid[rndI][rndJ].y;

            if (food != null) removeChild(food);  //if there is food on the grid removes the food from the board 

            food = makeItem(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);// random color
            food.x = rndX;
            food.y = rndY;

            addChild(food); //adds the food to the board

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < snake.length; i++){
                if (rndY == snake[i].y && rndX == snake[i].x){ 

                }
            } 
        }

        private function move(e:TimerEvent):void{
            if (left){
                curI -= 1;
            }else if (right){
                curI += 1;
            }
            if (up){
                curJ -= 1;
            }else if (down){
                curJ += 1;
            }

            if (left || right || up || down){
                var s:Sprite = makeItem();

                if (curI > DIM - 1) curI = 0;
                if (curJ > DIM - 1) curJ = 0;

                if (curI < 0) curI = DIM - 1;
                if (curJ < 0) curJ = DIM - 1;

                s.x = grid[curI][curJ].x;
                s.y = grid[curI][curJ].y;

                addChild(s);
                snake.push(s);


                 if (Math.floor(s.x) == Math.floor(food.x) && Math.floor(s.y) == Math.floor(food.y) ){ 
                 //placeFood(); } 
                 else if((tmr.currentCount % 10) > 0) { removeChild(snake[0]); snake.shift(); }
            }

        }

        private function changeDir(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)  {if (!right){left = true;  up = false; down = false; right = false;}}
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)    {if (!down) {left = false; up = true;  down = false; right = false;}}
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {if (!left) {left = false; up = false; down = false; right = true;}}
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)  {if (!up)   {left = false; up = false; down = true;  right = false;}}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event parameter to any function that's handling a TimerEvent.

```
private function placeFood(event:TimerEvent):void {
```

Comment: ahh cheers no more output/compiler errors. A quick question though, as the object sets of movement it just adds a trail, you wouldn;t know how tomake it so it only adds a body part every so often? I would of thought it would have been done by the timer but it doesn't work seems to ignore it.

Comment: public function Snake(){
   size = stage.stageWidth / DIM; //change grid size
   curI = curJ = Math.floor(DIM * 0.5); //change grid size

   initSnake();
   fillGrid();
   
   
   addSnake = new Timer(snakeAttach);
   addSnake.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,placeFood);
   addSnake.start();
   
   tmr = new Timer(SPEED);
   tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,move);
   tmr.start();
   
   stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,changeDir);
  }

Comment: the two timers one for snake movement and one for adding to the tail are in one function is that correct?

Comment: Ok, this is a bit of guesswork, but you have a function there called changeDir don't you?  I'm guessing that in this function a direction flag is set based on a keycode from the KeyboardEvent.  It's these flags that are tested in your move() function (the up|down|left|right variables).  Because it's called by a timer those flags won't be set, so the snake never grows.

Comment: yeah another function calls the keyboard directions. The snake moves but when you say press the up arrow it moves up but doesn't increment the snake objects. It just does a line if you get me. sorry for my terrible explanation

Comment: I could paste you all the code, it runs just from one document class and draws the items. Maybe it would be easier? thanks for your help btw id be lost else

Comment: The problem is where you've commented out part of the move function. This block is supposed to remove the last part of the snake, giving the illusion of movement. If you had picked up food this time new food would be placed, but importantly the last segment would not be removed, causing the snake to grow.  You could use a modulus of tmr.currentCount to cause the snake to grow every 10 moves like this: if (Math.floor(s.x) == Math.floor(food.x) && Math.floor(s.y) == Math.floor(food.y) ){ //placeFood(); } else if((tmr.currentCount % 10) > 0) { removeChild(snake[0]); snake.shift(); }

Comment: what function would that go in?

Comment: it replaces the if...else you commented out at the end of the move() function.

Comment: did you mean to comment out the placeFood(); part on that code?

Comment: yeah, I figured that you wouldn't want it to be called since you'd commented the block, but left it in for clarity

Comment: comes up with the error  Line 151 1083: Syntax error: else is unexpected?? any clues

Comment: that lines      else if((tmr.currentCount % 10) > 0) { removeChild(snake[0]); snake.shift(); }

Comment: you have a curly bracket on the same line as the commented call to placeFood().  That is the closing brace of the if, and so is required.

Comment: epic. thanks so much, you have saved me weeks of google searching. cheers pal

Comment: Hi shane, sorry to bug you again but i was just wondering is it simple to make it so the game stops when the snake hits its tail? would you do an if statement in the move function

Comment: Basically yes, you would run a hitTest against the snake body, probably using the newly added head piece before it gets pushed into the snake array.  The problem with this is that initially the snake starts with three segments on the same square.

Comment: private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event ):void
{
     if( snake.hitTestObject(s) ) { trace("hit") }
}

Comment: my syntax is a little off on the event gaining a 1046 error but would that work? by the way that is triggered by an enter frame listener

Comment: Probably not.  the 's' that's referred to there is a local variable in your move function.  What you really need to do is check when the new head segment is created that it's not being created on top of an existing segment.

Comment: Ahh yes, so would that be using a what would the hitTestObject refer to? the snake array and would it go within this part of the code - if (Math.floor(s.x) == Math.floor(food.x) && Math.floor(s.y) == Math.floor(food.y) ){ 
     } 
     else if((tmr.currentCount % 3) > 0) { removeChild(snake[0]); snake.shift(); }

Comment: I'm not really sure how best to do this.  I suppose you could either hittest the new head segment against all the other segments in the snake array, or maybe do something with tracking how many segments are on the grid square.

Comment: Hmmm you have any clues on how to code it to check if the head has hit any other objects in the array, struggling to know where to begin. thanks

Comment: I did actually start building a test for it, but I get an annoying false positive 2 out of three calls to move().  Work is a bit busy for me to persist right now, but you can download the class here: http://www.subdmedia.com/public_downloads/Snake.as.  You'll see that there is a new method testHit(), and the end of the move function has an additional check.  It's full of traces currently as it's WIP.

Comment: Thanks for that shane its a great help , does the function test hit grab the parts of the snake and set them as the variable segment correctly?

Comment: It runs the test on each Sprite in the array sequentially, but the false positive happens 2/3 times when testing the Sprite that is directly behind the head. This suggests that if the bounding boxes are next to each other but not overlapping then there can be an issue.  I was wondering if it is to do with a pixel not being rounded somewhere, not found it yet though.

Comment: Could i somehow use the placeFood funtion. as this detects whether there is food on the grid to before placing it. just change it so that you see if head has same coordinates as a body?

Comment: Been trying to have a go at it and only come up with this - private function checkForHits():void {
   for (var i:uint = 0; i < snake.length; i++){
    if (snake[0].y == snake[i].y && snake[0].x == snake[i].x){ 
     trace("hit")
        }
   else { trace("no hit")
   } 
   
}         Weird outputs though

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you had it in model-view-controller framework. You have a lot going on and the different listeners might not match up perfectly. Have the view class set the swf, add the snake to the stage, make the grid, hold listeners for inputs. Input then get processed by controller. Remember the View is basically the class that's added to stage and most follows the flow of the game. Have a _controller.startTimer(); function. Then all the stuff that you want to happen can be processed in the controller. And when you want the things to explode, change a model variable that tells the view to do that. Controller makes changes to all the variables (including the array of items on the field) stored in model, and when it's done making calculations it would change one of model's variables. Model would then trigger the changeHanldler function that calls view to move something, change some text, play a sound, switch screens, wiggle the snake, play your own tweened out snake wiggling....